# How to change MIME type with script in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to load an external script into my react file, and it is saying: refused to execute script from 'whereMyScriptIs" because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

How can I change the type to make it text/javascript? I have put the code below where I included the script. Any help would be appreciated!

```
componentDidMount () {
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "./live_w_locator.js";
script.async = true;
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

}

Comment: I just received this error the other day, how I fixed it was going into the URL and trying to load the script itself. Once i got the script loaded, i corrected the src path and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You should not include external javascript files like this. Instead you could simply add a `import './live_w_locator'` to the top of your file.

Comment: @PushedCrayon When you are importing it this way, you need to have a default export in the Javascript file. So at the end of the `live_w_locator.js` file, you need to add a `export default functionName`

Answer (score 0):

- `text/javascript` is obsolete
- `application/javascript` is the current official MIME type for JS

Instead of `script.type = "text/javascript"` you need to make sure script type is `application/javascript`

```
componentDidMount () {
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "./live_w_locator.js";
script.async = true;
script.type = "application/javascript"; // notice the change here
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

You can read more about Media Types on [Iana.org](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)